# Turtle clear() isn't working on list of Turtle objects

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics

I'm writing a simple Python snake game. As the snake eats food, it grows in length. My code adds new segments as Turtle objects to my list of segments. When the snake hits the border of the screen, my code is supposed to clear the segments off the screen and reset positions/text.

I'm having an issue clearing the segments off the screen. I thought something like this would work:

```
for segment in segments:
  segment.clear()

segments = []
```

But, the segment is still on the screen! However, when I use this code, somehow it works:

```
for segment in segments:
  segment.goto(10000, 10000)

segments = []
```

I thought clear() would work. What is wrong here? Btw, I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.edureka.co/blog/python-turtle-module/#BuildSnake%27sBody).

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
  for segment in segments:
      segments.remove(segment)
```

This will clear the segments list.

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't work. My question is more about why I'm unable to clear the canvas using clear().

Comment: You can clear the value in the list using the built in function in the turtle library. Here's how: `for segment in segments: segment.clear()`. And you dont have to do `segments = []`